# Let $X=\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$. Define the relation $R$ on $X$ by: for all $a,b\in X$, $aRb$ if and only if $ab$ is even.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question: Find the number of subsets $S$ of $X$ (of any size) that satisfy the following property: $\forall a \in S$, $\exists b \in S$ so that $a R b$.**

I have a discrete math final coming up and this was one of the questions on the practice final. The answer key for the test gives a different answer I really want to be sure.

The answer key says the answer is $2^{10}-2^5$ however i really think it should be $2^{10}-31$ or $2^{10}-2^5 +1$ since the way the answer key solved it was it subtracted the power set of all the possible subsets of just having odd elements from the power set of the main set.

This however, fails to take into account the empty set and I believe the empty set satisfies the condition vacuously as it says "for any elements $a,b$ in the set if $aRb$". Now, an empty set has no elements so it should vacuously satisfy the condition. Hence there are $31$ sets not $32$ that should be subtracted from $2^{10}$. Do you agree?

Comment: Your question is the same as asking for the number of sets that contain at least 1 even number from $X$ in it. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed.  You must ensure that the emptyset is not excluded from the sets being counted.

$\left\lvert 2^X\right\rvert -\left\lvert 2^{X\smallsetminus \{2,4,6,8,10\}}\smallsetminus \{\emptyset\}\right\rvert = 2^{10}-2^{5}+1$

---

To check, let $Y=\{1,2\}$, so that the analogous collection is $\{\{\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ which has size $2^2-2^1+1$.

Comment: Could you explain how or why an empty set satisfies the condition? I am having second thoughts if it does

Comment: It is a vacuous truth, as you stated.$$\forall a\in\emptyset~\exists b\in \emptyset:(2\mid ab)\\\lnot\exists a\in\emptyset~\forall b\in\emptyset:(2\nmid ab)$$So you must ensure that the emptyset is not excluded from the sets being counted.

Comment: sorry what is that notation in front of the "there exists" in the second line? basically it is vacuous because there are no elements in the empty set so there exists no counter example or implication that ab would be odd because a and b dont exist right?

Comment: $\lnot$ is "not". So the line does say "There is *not* an $a$ in the emptyset that serves as a counter example."